# What is the path of "my computer" folder on windows?

Tags: windows, winforms

I am working on a C++ windowsform project, using visual Studio IDE.
  I use `CFileDialog` class to ask the user to select a file to open. 
 It display an usual open file  selection windows. 
I would like the default folder displayed to be the same as the one accessed when clicked on "My computer", where the harddrives, USB drives, dvd drives etc. are displayed.

I can define default folder by writting its path to`lpstrInitialDir` member, but I don't find the path for such a folder. I tried "\", "explorer.exe", "", none of them gave me the expected result.
The application will be used by several users, so the solution must not include the user name in the path. i.e "C:\Documents and Settings[user]\Desktop\My Computer" may work but is not correct for my application.

Does anyone know of to define the "root" path of windows (i.e the root of C:\) ?

I searched on SO and internet but maybe I have used wrong keywords because I couldn't find appropriate content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`My Computer` is a virtual shell folder that doesn't correspond to any file system directory. There's no file system path that would correspond to that location.

Fortunately, file dialogs do speak "shellese", so you can use the CLSID (not to be confused with the GUID KNOWNFOLDERID or the CSIDL) of the shell folder. Sample in C# Winforms, but really, the only important part is the `::CLSID`):

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
ofd.ShowDialog();
```

*Disclaimer: I couldn't find any relevant documentation for the virtual folder CLSID, or this behaviour of the File dialog. So this is most likely not contractual, and could possibly change in future versions of Windows.*

Comment: Where did you get this GUID?

Comment: That's funny: it works, but the GUID is not referenced in the [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Thomas Honestly, I have no idea where I got it originally. Probably by looking at the "real" path in Explorer (don't ask me how to do that - I don't remember anymore :D). It's a CLSID in HKCR, of course, but that doesn't help when you're trying to find it in the first place. I couldn't find any relevant documentation, so it probably isn't contractual, but it's been there since like Windows 98 IIRC.

Comment: It works for me too. I will read on CLSID because I don't understand how this can work right now... If someone have documentation on where this ID come from or about its compatibility, thanks to add it.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dudu721 In general, CLSIDs are documented - that's how you write custom virtual folders for the shell. A simple Google search will get you the relevant MSDN docs. The shell looks up the CLSID in the registry to find out what extension handles that particular virtual folder. Only the "My computer" CLSID in particular is the "issue" here - it doesn't seem to be documented. It does work from Win 98 onwards, so backward compatibility isn't a big deal. It might be removed (or changed) in the future, but it's not very likely.

Comment: I can confirm this works, you can find all of these CSLID here: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\

Answer (score 1):

In the explorer, in the search bar copy the address of

```
This PC
```

and then select the text

```
This PC
```

and paste. Normally we get the

> Ce PC ":: {CLSID}"

and then just copy

```
:: {CLSID}
```

and paste it wherever we want.

Answer (score 0):

Path should be: C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Computer.lnk

Comment: This only works if the user has a shortcut named "Computer" on their desktop.

Comment: What about for This PC on Windows 10?