# Set defaultPath to This PC on Windows, Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, dialog, electron

I've tried setting the `defaultPath` to `This PC` as the path, but it doesn't wanna work. In desperation, I've also tried `\` and `.`, both of which also don't work. I've tried copying address from File Explorer, but it simply copies the text 'This PC'. I've tried right-clicking `This PC` in File Explorer to view its properties, but it sends me to `Control Panel > System and Security > System`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to set the `defaultPath` of Electron's `dialog.showOpenDialog` to This PC on Windows?

If not, I'll set it to `c:\\`, but I'd rather set the default path to an overview of all the drives.

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(
  remote.getCurrentWindow(),
  {
    title: 'Select Archives to Analyze',
    buttonLabel: 'Select Archives',
    defaultPath: 'This PC',
    properties: [ 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections', 'showHiddenFiles' ]
  }
)
.then(res => !res.canceled && saveDirs(res.filePaths))
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065536/what-is-the-path-of-my-computer-folder-on-windows) I don't think it's possible :/

Comment: @pergy damn that would suck. ill take a look. ive also tried various things like `'\'`, `'.'`, but neither worked.